# PHP/MYSQL having getting correct if/else results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I have a bio page which shows the user their email and gives them the option to set their email to be public on other pages. By default the privacy column is set to NULL which means private.

In my privacy column in my database, the field starts of null/blank for all users.
The below code assumes that a user starts with a blank privacy value which I am calling the private status. The initial message should say "your email is set to private"

Something is wrong of course. We see the text "Your email is set to public" and the button that says "set to private"

But when I click the button to make public, the privacy value is changed to n and the page refreshes as it should but it shows the exact same message "your email is public" and the set to public button.

```
if(isset($_POST ['private'])){

$priv = $_POST['private'];
$sql = "UPDATE wp_users SET privacy = :private WHERE ID = :ID";
$stmt3 = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt3->bindParam(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt3->bindParam(':private', $priv, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt3->execute(); 
?>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://example.com/bio/">
<?php
}
else {


$currentpriv = $current_user->privacy;
if ($currentpriv = NULL) {
?>

Your email is set to private <form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Set to public</button>
<input type="hidden" name="private" value="n">
</form>
<?
} 
else {
?>


//BELOW IS THE BLOCK OF CODE THAT DISPLAYS ON THE PAGE NO MATTER WHAT, EVEN 
//AFTER I CLICK THE BUTTON AND THE VALUE OF PRIVACY IS CHANGED FROM NULL TO n.

Your email is set to public<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Set to private</button>
<input type="hidden" name="private" value=NULL>
</form>
<?
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Where does `$current_user` come from and how is its `privacy` property set? Can you check the database directly to see if the `privacy` field is actually updated?

Comment: $current_user is a wordpress method. It corresponds to a users table which stores the user IDs and emails and now the custom privacy column I created. That works fine though. If I do echo $current_user->privacy, it will correctly echo whatever i manually type in there like y or n

Comment: Just tweakend things a bit and updated the question. I have privacy set to null/no value. The code above will set privacy to n as it should but does not change the text to say "your email is set to public"

Comment: print `$currentpriv` after it is set to see its value like `echo $currentpriv; exit;`

Comment: It will print the value of privacy if I do that. Currently "n" since I clicked the button which change the value to n

Comment: I made a few tweaks with same result. changed if ($currentpriv = NULL) in code. See //comment in code

Comment: Could the problem be that I have else twice and not elseif?

Comment: This `$currentpriv = NULL` isn't a comparison. It should at least be `$currentpriv == NULL`

Comment: Nice...Almost there. With the == change it now starts executes the correct block. But when I click the button to set it back to null, the database updates with just N (the first letter of NULL). What is the syntax to change it back to null in the second form?

Comment: To add to my last comment...when I try to set it back to null in the other button, I just need to figure out how to complete the problem. This isn't correct: <input type="hidden" name="private" value=NULL>

Answer (score -1):

Try using bindValue()

> $stmt3->bindValue(':ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
>   $stmt3->bindValue(':private', $priv, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: The PDO is working fine though, so I don't think that is a factor.  If I print the values of privacy i get what it should be and the value is being updated correctly when I click the button the first time. But it just won't display the correct block of code if value is set by the button